# Loading XAML (WinRT/C++) window in Win32 static library

Tags: c++, xaml, winapi, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

There is a solution with two projects.
The first is executable, the second is a static library which is loaded in the executable project. My necessary (desired) code must be placed in a static library. With helping WinRT/C++ API it's necessary to load and show the window described using the XAML-layout.

There are [many examples](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-appsample-Xaml-Hosting) when in Win32 project, window  will use new items from UWP, but this is not what I need. In addition XAML-Islands technology (so it is called) requires the latest version Windows 10 (1903).

I also found several examples that seem to do what I need, but because of the problems of the executable threads (as I understood), my code cannot be executed in a static library: https://youtu.be/eHCDTsQrTX8

Thus, I ask for help: how can I load and call the XAML window within a static library of Win32, without violating the integrity of threads. Thanks.

Comment: I did not understand your question. Why did you want to call XAML window in a static library? What's the effect that you want to achieve?

Comment: [Bite](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7924641/bite), there is a native module for an Electron. It's written and executed in C++. This module uses a static library in which there is a work with GUI written on a terrible ATL/WTL. But for Windows10 I want to use WinRT/c++ code with XAML within this static library.

Answer (score 1):

As of Windows 10 1903, a process is either a Win32 process or a UWP process. Win32 processes can create Win32 windows (HWND) but not UWP windows (CoreWindow); for UWP processes it's the other way around. So there's no way for a Win32 process to directly create a CoreWindow.

Your options are either (1) create a Win32 window and use XAML Islands to host XAML UI within it or (2) use the Desktop Bridge to bundle a Win32 app with a UWP app and have them appear to the end user as one combined app; you can then use interprocess communication to have the UWP app tell the Win32 app to create a HWND or have the Win32 app tell the UWP app to create a CoreWindow.